# Installing a Certificate in IIS 7

Tags: security, iis, ssl, iis-7

I have created a free certificate from https://www.startssl.com. It asked me to export that certificate on the disk. Now i want to install this certificate in IIS 7 on my webserver. How do i do that. In server certificate when i click on complete certificate request, it appears in IIS but again disappears on refresh. why is that? I read somewhere on the internet that we'll have to import the certificate in our computer before we can start using it.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a certificate request you generate a secret part and keep it yourself, this guarantees that the response from the certificate issuer can not be intercepted and used by anyone but yourself.  When you complete your request the response is combined with the part you kept to make a complete certificate with private key which is then put into one of your certificate stores. The response file can then be discarded as it can not be used directly.

To use the certificate look in your certificate stores and select it and/or export with the private key to use on other webservers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a weird bug in IIS 7/7.5 where certificates disappear from the console right after import. Close the console, log off, log back on and open the IIS certificate console again. You should now see it listed (hopefully)